# Can "better off" stand by itself in a sentence as a reply?

Tags: grammar

**For example:**

**Ana**: 
You shouldn't be with Josh, he always joshing you. (haha)

**Cindy**:
I know, he's mean. I should be by myself.

**Ana**: **You're better off.**

shouldn't it be **"You're better off without him"?**

Comment: Either version is fine: the "without him" isn't required, but it's not bad to have it. However, Ana should say, "**You'd be** better off," because she's referring to a situation that is hypothetical.

Comment: I agree with @CanadianYankee- if Cindy says “I’ve broken up with him” then it would make sense for Ana to say “You’re better off” in the present indicative. Either “...this way” or “...without him” could be added to this statement but the meaning is understood as is.

Answer (score 1):

In context "You're better off" is correct. It is understood to mean "... without him". But the phrase "without him" is omitted. This is a common enough expression for a person to understand what is meant without the full expression being used. It is quite reasonable for this kind of omission to be made in colloquial speech.